# Derive from COM interface - base methods not visible

Tags: c#, com

I am working with a COM interface from an SDK. I would like to add helper methods to the base interface, so I derive a class from it, but none of the base methods are visible in the derived object. Why is that? How can I accomplish my need?

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseCOMInterface {}

BaseCOMInterface b = new BaseCOMInterface();
Derived d = new DerivedClass();

b.Method(); // this works
d.Method(); // Method() not found
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the your "base" class `BaseCOMInterface` is not declared `public`

Make the base class `public`

```
public class BaseCOMInterface {}
```

Comment: Adding 'public' modifier results in 'Type Expected' error